# React (Gutenberg) DateTimePicker that does not show inline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

For a liveblog I have created a Gutenberg block where users can add liveblog-items. Each item has a date and time, so I decided to use the [DateTimePicker](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/components/src/date-time):

```
<DateTimePicker
  currentDate={liveblog.datetime}
  value={liveblog.datetime}
  onChange={datetime => {
    const newObject = Object.assign({}, liveblog, {
      datetime: datetime
    });
    props.setAttributes({
      items: [
        ...items.filter(
          item => item.index != liveblog.index
        ),
        newObject
      ]
    });
  }}
  is12Hour={false}
/>
```

My issue is, this renders the whole element inline. I would prefer to just show the date and time that were picked, and when a user clicks it, the DateTimePicker would show. It all examples I have found, this behavior is the default (with an input field showing), but to me it seems it is not. How do I get the picker to 'pop up' ?

I tried to create a button that calls a function to return the element like so:

```
const toggleDateTimePicker = (liveblog) => {

  return <DateTimePicker
    currentDate={liveblog.datetime}
    value={liveblog.datetime}
    onChange={datetime => {
      const newObject = Object.assign({}, liveblog, {
        datetime: datetime
      });
      props.setAttributes({
        items: [
          ...items.filter(
            item => item.index != liveblog.index
          ),
          newObject
        ]
      });
    }}
    is12Hour={false}
  />
};
```

and:

```
<Button onClick={(liveblog) => toggleDateTimePicker (liveblog)} >test</Button>
```

The function is called correctly, but it does not render/show anything.